# How do I ask / combine 2 SQL SELECTS and put the result in a php variable? [cIosed]

Tags: sql

I want to combine

```
SELECT * FROM form
```

with

```
SELECT REPLACE(/var/WWW/html, "/var", "/vur")
```

After that I want to put it in a php variable.

I tried this:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM form" with "SELECT REPLACE (/var/WWW/html, "/var", "/vur")"
```

I want SELECT everything of my database but I also want to replace text from one column.

It should be like this:

1. select everything of the database
2. replace text of column no. 12
3. put it in a variable

Is this possible? And how?

Comment: what is the name of column 12?

Comment: Do you want ALL the columns ( i.e. * ) or just the replaced value of column ??12??

Comment: I want to get everything (*) and I want to replace "/var" with "/vur" from column "businessCard". :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have understand your issue, this query should solve it

```
SELECT *, REPLACE(myColumn, "/var", "/vur") something FROM form
```

Comment: I will check it in a minute but I think its the right way :)

Comment: Don't worry :) I also advise you not to use the SELECT *, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you searched for the SQL UNION command.